# How to get a function from one class into another function in another class

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class

I'm trying to use a function from one class and use it in another function in another class.
classTest.php

```
class Test extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
    public function testing(){
       $anotherClass = new anotherClass;
       $anotherClass->testFunction();
    }
}
```

anotherClass.php

```
class anotherClass{
    public function testFunction(){
        echo "This is the test function";
    }
}
```

I hope I made sense

Answer (score 0):

In your `classTest.php`

Include The `anotherClass.php` first then Create object of anotherClass using  `$anotherClass = new anotherClass();` and call the function of  another Class `$anotherClass->testFunction();`

```
include ("anotherClass.php");
class Test extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
    public function testing(){
       $anotherClass = new anotherClass();
       $anotherClass->testFunction();
    }
}
```

> Or

```
class A
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'Some Name';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function getNameOfA()
    {
        return $this->a->getName();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);

$b->getNameOfA();
```

In this example is first create a new instance of the `A` class. And after that I have created a new instance of the `B` class to which I pass the instance of `A` into the constructor. Now `B` can access all the public members of the `A` class using `$this->a`.

Also note that I don't instantiate the `A` class inside the `B` class because that would mean I tighly couple the two classes. This makes it hard to:

1. unit test your `B` class
2. swap out the `A` class for another class

Comment: I added the `include('Test/src/anotherClass.php');` but I'm getting an error `Fatal error: Class 'anotherClass' not found`

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions from any other class just need to include the required class into your php file, so in your example, if you want to make a call to test function:

```
<?php
include_once('anotherClass.php');

class Test extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
    public function testing(){
       $anotherClass = new anotherClass;
       $anotherClass->testFunction();
    }
}
```